# Tracking users in Rails 4 - Sessions, cookies, encrypted cookies?! Need a simple authentication guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, cookies

I am new to Rails and I tried the following tutorial [Railscast 270 Basic Authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1).
However, somehow I get an error because rails does not find the 'session'. Somewhere I read I dont have to manually generate a model/table for it?

So now I read that active record sessionstore has been deprecated and/or gemified? What I want is a simple registration/login/logout mechanism to start with but I wanna do it 'the right way' avoiding old and deprecated stuff.

Can someone guide me or link me to a tutorial which is still valid?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are loads here you can watch: http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=authentication

I'd personally recommend following this specific one, although it may require a paid account:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised

If you aren't willing to pay a little money, then starting with this one wouldn't be too bad either:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1

It says it's for Rails 3.1, but it'll work in 4 without much (if any) additional effort.

Comment: I saw all of those and thats part of my question, what should I use? some of the railcasts are pretty old...

Answer (score 0):

Hartl's Rails Tutorial (updated for Rails 4) has a very clear explanation of setting up your own authentication system from scratch: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-signin_failure

If you're new to Rails, it's definitely not a conceptual walk in the park. I urge you to sit down and really think about what every single line of code is doing - you could get away with copy/pasting huge parts of code to implement your authentication system, but at that point you might as well use a gem like Devise to do it for you.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look at it. At the moment I implemented it with the session[] hash as described in http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails-4